# Computer hanged in the middle of bios flashing process

Tags: bios, hardware-failure, toshiba-laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to recover a computer from a failed BIOS update?](https://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update)

I have a laptop: Toshiba Satellite c660-17j, today I decided to update BIOS. I've downloaded bios updater from manufacturer's web site, and in the middle of flashing process computer hanged. I was waiting more than 30 minutes, but nothing was changed on the screen, i've tryed to PRESS MORE BUTTONS, but there were no reactions, so i've turned it off by removing battery (all other methods failed, even pressing power button for ~10 secs). After that computer can't start.

I understand, that there's MESS in BIOS chip, and it's possible to re-flash it with hardware programmer, but I don't have it.

I remember, that on some PCs (even on my eeepc) there was possibility to re-flash bios by inserting usb flash-disk (with .dat file on it, which contained BIOS), and power on PC, while holding some keys combination, then PC was switching to BIOS programming mode and re-flashed BIOS, after that it was possible to boot up normaly.

Is there a way to recover computer without hardware programming BIOS chip?

Comment: Apparently it is possible. http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=37865

Comment: To start, perhaps check out your model's manual for information on what to do in this scenerio.  But really I'd suggest/plan on calling Toshiba for advice, as they may have a utility they can point you towards. My guess though, is you may be out of luck and need ot send it in to them for a reflash or replacement of the BIOS chip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to recover a computer from a failed BIOS update?](http://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update) also see: http://superuser.com/questions/486232/recover-a-pc-from-a-corrupted-bios-using-a-second-pc?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/390189/how-can-i-recover-my-notebook-from-a-failed-bios-update?lq=1