# Cannot stop my computer from going into the BIOS automatically

Tags: boot, bios, asus-laptop

I bought a laptop ASUS PU500CA with FreeDOS installed.
First time when I turned it on I got a FreeDOS command line. I tried to run `dir` to check that everything is all right. It returned a list o files. It seemed that everything was all right...

Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04.
After that when I am rebooting I see only BIOS blue screen.

In a boot tab there is only such information:

```
Boot configuration
Launch PXE OpROM disbaled
```

There is no an option of booting with HDD.

But in the Advanced tab there is info about HDD (Hitachi...)
When I push ESC or F10 to exit from BIOS It enters BIOS again and again...

What is this?

PS: I forgot to say that

> Boot Option Properties

in tab Boot is unavailable for choosing.

Comment: you write "When I push ESC or F10 to exit from BIOS It enters BIOS again and again..."  <-- what if you push nothing. does it still goes into the bios?

Comment: @barlop, if I restart a laptop first thing I see is a blue bios screen

Comment: Flashing the BIOS isn't a bad idea, if you can manage it and have the courage, and you should have the courage once you know what's involved. What if you push F11, does it let you choose to boot what you want?

Comment: @barlop. when I push F11 nothing happens

Comment: The BIOS has been around for longer than i've lived and i've been surrounded by computers for about two decades and never seen a computer that keeps booting into the BIOS and is stuck in the bios and won't let you exit!  but you can move around your bios I assume?i'm not sure specifically what your bios looks like though. It doesn't sound like your keyboard but  what if you try a different keyboard? There may be a jumper on the motherboard to reset the bios that might help

Comment: Maybe it goes to the BIOS automatically when it can't boot from anything. So you could try removing freedos and trying to install ubuntu on its own and see if that works.

Comment: @barlop, You didn't understand me. With BIOS Everything is all right. It responds my keyboard. The problem is when I push a ESC the laptop tries to restart but returns to BIOS.

Comment: @barlop - The author already tried that.  He currently has Ubuntu installed.

Comment: What does it say will happen you press escape?  Of course its safe to update the BIOS firmware.  Of course its safe to update the firmware.  Its the only way to add support for new hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound, ESC -> 'Quit without saving?' -> yes -> it tries to reboot but opens a BIOS window immediately again.

Comment: **The behavior indicates that its not detecting a bootable disk.**

Comment: @Ramhound the author doesn't state that he installed ubuntu fresh, and it's possible it didn't install correctly.  And when he asked if flashing the bios is safe, you say yes. flashing the BIOS has some serious risks attached, for example, if it goes wrong, here is a link about how to recover http://superuser.com/questions/486232/recover-a-pc-from-a-corrupted-bios-using-a-second-pc   If  a person doesn't flash with the right version then it may cause a serious problem. Though i've always flashed the right one. But flashing the BIOS is famously something that carries a lot of warnings.

Comment: Does It mean that Better for me is to return the laptop to seller?

Comment: @barlop - I guess I am so use using hardware with both primary and recovery firmware I forget its possible to corrupt the firm. Doesn't change the fact that based on the description it either needs to be done to restore full functionality of the firmware or the drive itself is not bootable.  Its really hard to flash the wrong firmware, I find most people, go out of their way to do that.

Comment: @LeshaPipiev Try to install ubuntu fresh. Also you can contact the seller and see if he has any ideas re the problem. You could enquire about returning it I suppose. But he may want to see if there really is a fault and there may not be

Comment: @barlop, I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Is it fresh?

Comment: @LeshaPipiev  I mean delete any partitions prior to installing it. So it doesn't see freedos there. Deleting partitions can be done off many OS installation CDs.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue..hit much website for solution but there was no problem with my CMOS battery, stuck keyboard,HDD,ram etc. I just turned off my main switch and then turn it on.....everything is fine now and windows boots appropriately.

I inserted every USB device like mouse keyboard and sound cords as they were in before and my windows keep booting properly as before but after the American Megatrend problems! I

know that many things could make it no working but by this event I have just realised - sometimes you have to take risky decision and turn off the main power plug!

Oh one event was the culprit I guess ... Today I installed a driver toolkit software. It might cause the problem though i uninstalled it before shutting down the PC due to the fake service of this software!

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"