# HP DL140 G3, how to repair after failed BIOS update?

Tags: bios, restore, flashing, hp-proliant

During updating BIOS to the new version (1.18) I got an error that computer can't read rom file. Then after reboot server did not start. Actually it starts but does not show anything, screen is blank, no system beeps or led signals.

The question is, how can I recover it? I can't find any information about.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience on this, and I can tell you that your computer is **dead**. Sorry but that's the truth, there's no (officially) known way to repair or recover a *badly flashed bios image*. You're stuck with these options:

1. Send it to the manufacturer to repair.
2. Buy a new motherboard.
3. Sell it as parts and buy a new computer (if it's a laptop).

There are very few software issues that can render a PC useless, and this is one of them (if not the only).

Alternatively, and given the correct knowledge, you may want to take a look at [**this question**](https://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update).

Comment: You say there is no known way to recover a badly flashed bios firmware yet you link to a question with ways to do exactly that?

Comment: @Ramhound I said it's not official way, like a proper procedure on certain models or for certain kinds of motherboards.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I recover it?

There are a few ways depending on the motherboard:

- If it has the firmware in an EEPROM you can remove that and flash it on an external computer. I have seen this work after a failed flash when we had two identical systems. Boot #1, while powered on pull the EEPROM and replace it with the blank one. Flash firmware.
- If you have the right tools, remove the EEPROM and use an external burner.
- if it has a BIOS recovery mode then enable the right jumper. This often enables a minimal boot system which can be used to flash the firmware. Sometimes this involves putting the firmware ROM contents in a very specific place. (e.g. on a USB2 pen drive with a specifically named file in a specific location).
- If it has dual BIOS then move the jumper to switch to the second BIOS and boot.

Sadly all of these are rather generic. The first only works if the chip is socketed and you have an identical machine to swap with. The other options are common on modern high end motherboards, but I am not aware of these options on any server motherboards.

Lastly you might get success if the board has JTAG headers. Those allow you to 'debug' and may allow flashing of the boards firmware. Something easily done in a service center, but not tools which you find in monst households. If you have friends with microcontrollers, rPi's etc then you might be lucky though.

That leaves only two practical solutions:

1. Grab a new motherboard (with working firmware) off ebay.
2. Take it to a servuice center or phone repair place which has the tools.

Last remark: [this post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/606674/hp-dl140-g3-how-to-repair-after-failed-bios-update) seems to assume it has an EEPROM chip.