# HP dv6930es bios upgrade fail

Tags: bios

Days ago I was upgrading the BIOSs but a restart fails and now the laptop doesn't starts. When I plug the battery charger the connector lights turn on... but nothing else is running in the laptop.

I have been trying to do a BIOS recovery following the steps found in other sites, making a USB with wincris, the last bios version, etc. hiting Win + B keys...but I have not been able to recovery the laptop.

Some one can describe step by step all the process?

I heard that the best solution is to replace the corrupted bios chip for another one whit a correct bios version.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Why make a recovery on a USB if the machine isn't turning on?

Comment: @Dave I read that if you put the alst version of the bios in a USB bootable and hit the Power button at the same time you are hitting Win+B keys, the laptot goes into a recovery mode and recover the bios from the USB

Comment: Yes, but your post suggests it doesn't turn on at all... If the machine doesn't turn on then it won't be able to read the USB

Comment: So What can I do?

Comment: I think the only option is to send it back to HP, or a computer centre. Although you clearly have power to the plug, it appears to not be powering the laptop. Can you try plugging the laptop in and removing the battery and see if turns on?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dave. If I remove the battery and I plug the battery charger the connector light turns on

Comment: But does the laptop turn on when you try (does it respond at all, visually, or any sounds)?

Comment: Not at all. The only light I see is the light from battery charger connector. No any other light or sound are presents...

Comment: Bin it or send it back (or to a repair center).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to recover a computer from a failed BIOS update?](http://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update)

Answer (score 0):

by the sound of it your bios is bricked - I would get in contact with HP and see if they can help with it as it will need a new bios chip, or worst case a new mainboard