# Replace wiped BIOS on ASUS P5B-V motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios

I attempted to use AsusUpdate to update the BIOS of a ASUS P5B-V motherboard.

The update first wiped the BIOS of the motherboard, and when trying to write the new BIOS, it failed. It advised to try again, and I did, and I couldn't write the BIOS.

When the PC is turned on, the screen is black, no beeps occur, and no BIOS loads.

I've tried changing the CLRTC jumper from off to on, ([link](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1000851)), but that made no change, and I removed the CMOS battery, and changed the CLRTC jumper from off to on, and that made no change too.

What are my options? Thanks.

Comment: I'm reading a training doc, and it says "Note that you can also reset the BIOS by removing the battery on the motherboard for 30 minutes." - I haven't tried this yet - I will.

Comment: Removing the BIOS battery for 30 minutes did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Steve, I recommend checking out a similar question asked in SU. http://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update

Comment: The [last released BIOS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5B_V/HelpDesk_Download/) for this motherboard dates from 2007. Why did you decide to update it now and where did you get your version? I suggest to go back to the BIOS in my link.

Comment: It looks like this may already have good answers in the SU question mentioned in The_Foxx's answer.  The open bounty will prevent marking this as a duplicate, but consider doing that once the bounty is gone.  If those answers work for you, you might want to see if a moderator would cancel the bounty, mark this as a duplicate, and save you the rep.

Comment: @fixer1234: The answer linked-to by The_Foxx needs advanced hardware knowledge and is not for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try ASUS Crash Free BIOS 3. (install it on usb, it might take your bios automatically).
2. You can try also UNIFLASH. http://uniflash.software.informer.com/
3. Try these guys http://www.badflash.com/
4. If you can get your hands on a working ASUS bios chipset, you can try hot swap, meaning you power your pc with working bios, set the System BIOS cacheable option in the BIOS to enabled. While the pc is on replace the working bios with the corrupt one and flash it..