# How to restore a backup after BIOS update fail?

Tags: bios

If someone has made a BIOS backup (On a CD), and than updated his mainboard's BIOS, but the update failed,

How can that person restore The previous BIOS version from the CD? What are the stages of such typical procedure?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that it failed while attempting the flash itself? thats generally the last phase of the update process. If the flash hasn't occured, then the bios should be the same as it was. if it failed during the flash however it is likely bricked (in the true sense, in that the manufacturer must now be involved in the repair). In that case you will have to return it to the manufacturer (RMA) for repair or replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the motherboard boot up at all? If it doesn't boot up and if it doesn't have a dual BIOS feature then your only options are RMA'ing it to the manufacturer or reflashing the EEPROM by yourself.

Comment: Right now I'm asking only theoretically... Please, what is the meaning of, RMA'ing it to the manufacturer or reflashing the EEPROM by yourself?

Comment: If you have a single-EEPROM motherboard and the update fails, your motherboard shouldn't boot at all. Your only options in that case are sending it back to the manufacturer for warranty or reflashing the BIOS by yourself, which can be a little bit complicated. See this answer for instructions on reflashing: http://superuser.com/a/29466/532997