# BIOS gone wrong after update. Dead PC? Black screen

Tags: windows, bios, motherboard, crash, black-screen-of-death

I did a normal BIOS update. It completed successfully.

But then the normal restart after BIOS installation never happened
the PC went into a black screen. How can I fix this?

- **BIOS Version**: 3211 2021/08/26
- **Motherboard**: PRIME-B450M-A-ASUS-3211

The PC is under one year old, and all other BIOS updates went fine and had no such problem.

- The power (to the PC) wasn’t interrupted during the update.
- No overclocking or any modifications to the BIOS.
- USB is FAT32, and was only with the file provided By ASUS.(like always)

What I tried to do to fix this.

1. Unplug. Wait. Plug it back in again.
2. Reset the CMOS battery.
3. Check the RAM.
4. Use a recovery USB flash drive [as explained here](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012219/) on the official ASUS site.

What can I do? Did I miss something? Is the motherboard dead?

Comment: "The PC is Under one Year," so likely fully covered under warranty. Contact vendor and/or ASUS *in writing*, as well as by email or phone, to establish that you have a claim within warranty. then contact ASUS tech support, who will have good reason to help.

Comment: It's Not Covered By Warranty, Because its user Error .
Also The Warranty is Only 3 Moths
@DrMoishe

Comment: so lots of people misuse the word "brick", to describe something they did that they can fix.  Flashing an EPROM is one of the few activities that can actually "Brick" your device, meaning there is nothing YOU can do to repair it other than replacing the affected part. You will have to have it professionally serviced by the manufacturer or a partner.  Sorry. if it helps, it doesn't sound like you did anything wrong, and there are lots of safeguards that to prevent accidents, but flashing a rom is always a little risky.

Comment: So This Computer is Dead, and nothing that I do will fix it?
I researched this topic and the thing that comes up is the 
"CH341A 24 25 Series EEPROM Flash BIOS USB Programmer Module"

Comment: Going to sound silly, but I would recommend removing the CMOS battery and let the motherboard sit unpowered for a few days. Like completely disconnect the power. Also, try removing all PCI cards and RAM and reinstalling them again. I’ve experienced things like that and sometimes allowing the motherboard capacitors time to fully discharge can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to recover a computer from a failed BIOS update?](https://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update)

Comment: "USB is FAT3," - You sure about that? The type of tool you used typically uses FAT16

Comment: I saw that today, and I have a different motherboard BUT
The Device that he used may fix the issue 
Its Called "CH341A"
But I Want To Try Everything to fix this 
Before Spending 500$+ on a new motherboard, or sanding it to a PC lab.

Comment: **USB is FAT32/FAT16
Its Recommended by ASUS
@Ramhound

Comment: @thefourCraft - Except you wrote **FAT 3**

Comment: My bad, It Happens to the best of us

Comment: @Giacomo1968, that is truly epic, but it does convince me that fixing a bad flash is something that is just out of reach for the vast majority of operators, since it requires custom hardware, and likely modifications for each motherboard and its capabilities (for instance, parallel ports are rare these days, and not all manufacturers have an SPI header, or may have different pinouts). great read though! very kewl.

Comment: It worked for him because of his motherbord. I didn't understand the rest.

Comment: @FrankThomas - It’s easy provided the motherboard has a primary and secondary firmware or specifically provide a function to patch firmware outside of a POST environment. Even if everything is done write updating firmware doesn’t come without risks.

Comment: This motherbord doesn't have "EZ Bios". I ordered the CH341A programmer. I read that this is can fix the BIOS (completely dead).

Comment: Let us know how it works out! sounds interesting!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**How To Fix A Dead PC After BIOS Gone Wrong.**

So You Did it, you unplugged the Power or installed the wrong BIOS
And now you can't enjoy your shiny PC it's just a box of metal with spinning fans.
If you go online and read some of the "solutions" most of them say that your PC is dead and you need to throw it in the .

**BUT** you can fix it!! You Need To Be Motivated and have some spare time

⚠️Keep in mind that I'm **NOT** A Professional | You are doing this at your own risk!!⚠️

This will be different for each PC

### READ ME

If you are Under 13 Please Ask Your Guardians For Help, We are working with expansive Parts and electricity

⚠️⛔️**DO NOT RISK IT**⛔️⚠️

Before you try any of Those Fixes do the simple solutions Like:
Unplug the cable wait 30 seconds put it back in
restart the PC

1. **Confirm✅**
   Make Sure that this is a BIOS problem, check all the connections for your PC.
   Maybe you did everything right and it's just a cable not connected fully.
   Its recommended to connect the display to your motherboard and not into the GPU.
   Also, Check If the Display is on, and it works.
2. **The Start**
   Now we need to discount the PC from power, Put your PC on a sturdy table
   Take the front cover off, Find the CMOS Battery. Remove it from the motherboard Wait 2 min and put it back in.
   I found this video to be quite helpful:
   https://youtu.be/S9hyEPTFR10
   After the 2min is over put the CMOS Battery back in and try to start the PC

**⚠️DO NOT:⚠️** Put it on a bed\or unstable surface
Please make sure that the place you are going to be working is clean

3. **Mr.Shorter** 
   If the second step didn't work try to Hard reset the BIOS, This Deppens on each motherboard module, some motherboards have a button that you can press,
   Please Serch your model and find how to Hard reset your BIOS.
   Most motherboards have a 2 PIN system

Basically:
you take smoothing metal and hold it next to certain PINs on the mother Bord
On the motherboard manual, it should be labeled CLRTC
you need to shorten the Pins For 15 - 10 seconds.
Than Plug your PC back in and try to enter the BIOS

**⚠️Warning:⚠️** This Will Remove BIOS and restore to the factory version
this means that if you overclocked your pc or changed something with the BIOS it will be gone forever.

4. **Help DOS**☢️
   Most motherboard manufacturers provide repair shops with a DOS, essentially it's a program that runs on an external USB and fixes the BIOS.
   To Find This usually, you need to do a lot of searching or contact the support
   If you are lucky and found a restore program for your BIOS

Do The Following

Before you Plug the USB you need to format it to FAT16\FAT32
FAT16 is the most recommended. Use an empty USB drive that is more than 1GB.
Plug the USB ONLY to the BACK!!
After this starts the PC and the program should boot you back into BIOS.
If you are struggling to find a recovery program contact a local repair shop and maybe if they are nice they will help you free of charge.

5.**The Final Battle**
Well if everything didn't work this is the last useful thing that you can do before you check part by part to find the problem.
Go to Amazone.com\ebey.com Order A CH341A Programmer:
[Amazone Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SHSL9X9)

You Need To Follow This Video on how to do it:
https://youtu.be/4qX2zihB6UE

If There is No Hardware Problem this Will Probably be it.

6. **LEGO**
   So, Nothing is Working you Tried Everything, Now you need to check if all the parts are good on your computer. if you can test them on a separate PC then you might still have a chance to fix the problem.

**⚠️Warning:⚠️** You Must Know what are you doing Before you disconnect something or change something if you donk know then contact a local repair shop and pay the Fine I guess...

### **Tips:**

Try Downgrading A BIOS Version, Install an older Version
maybe the newest version has some kind of problem like in my case.

Start With No Video Card

### Some Useful Links

Asus: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1012219/
MSI: https://www.msi.com/page/biosflash
Gigabyte: https://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?topic=15067.0

Comment: even an IT expert would have to read your "answer" very carefully to see what answer you are advising.  Essentially you advise a)removing CMOS battery to reset the BIOS or b)resetting the BIOS by connecting two pins on the motherboard for that purpose or c)booting off USB with something from the motherboard manufacturer like maybe flashing the BIOS again this time with the right one  (I'm not sure that "C" would be possible though in the case of the question)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on an Asus B550 Pro Tuf Gaming. I think my GPU wasn't registering correctly.

So one last resort is to power up unplugging the power to the GPU. Let it go through the motions of failing. Then power down, re-plug the GPU power back in. The lights on my motherboard indicated everything was fine and got my signal back to the monitor.

Comment: Good idea, but I'd remove the GPU completely. Just unplugging the power can do more harm than good.