# Windows Using Too Much Reserved RAM Over 4GB?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, bios

This all started with a Problem in My BIOS Read [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1702827/bios-gone-wrong-after-update-dead-pc-black-screen?noredirect=1#comment2622057_1702827)

**About The Windows Using To Much Reserved Ram**

This is why I did a BIOS update in the first place. I was having the problem that windows used too much-Allocated RAM, So I thought this was an excellent time to update BIOS.

Due to my BIOS problem, I checked every component of the system to make sure that it was working. Everything worked well, with no issues on the "test PC". So I put it back in, fixed the BIOS Problem and got back into windows, and discovered that Windows is using 3GB+ of Reserved RAM

What I did to Fix:
Basically everything on the internet
Resetting the BIOS
Taking one RAM out and in
Changing the setting in windows

**PC Specs:**
Click the Link [Here](https://mclo.gs/k3wtAd9)

[Task Manger](https://superuser.com/questions/1702827/bios-gone-wrong-after-update-dead-pc-black-screen?noredirect=1#comment2622057_1702827)

### RAMMAP

[CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fmMc.png)

Comment: All the screenshots are of some random software. How does it relate to Windows using too much RAM? How much is too much? Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s Memory view on the Performance tab.

Comment: I edited it
hear is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK7ea.png

Comment: Ah. So you’re referring to hardware-reserved memory, correct?

Comment: yes, I know that windows is spouse to use 100MB or something.
On my main PC its 128MB
I don't get how its even Possible

Comment: Windows uses as much free memory as it can as a Disk Cache. You have 4 GB free memory that Windows' can't find a use for (as your programs don't want it) so it uses it to cache the disk.

Comment: Your error is coming from a bug in your IObit Advanced SystemCare stuff.  Their code is trying to read a Date from the registry without either having a number to read or providing a valid place to put it (uninitialized).  I can't see that this has anything to do with anything.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, But the RAM Bug Is Still present @SeñorCMasMas 
I Just Don't Get It How it's Possible, like Windoses Just Grew Bigger 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK7ea.png

Comment: @thefourCraft Look at RAMMAP  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: It's Not Showing Up On RAMMAP
This is Windows Allocated Ram, it's only doing it on this PC. 
No matter how much RAM I put in 3GB is hardware reserved
This is Living 12GB for the PC

Answer (score 1):

## It Was A BIOS!

The problem was in the BIOS configuration, the internal GPU was using too much RAM.
After Configuring it to 50MB everything was fine.\

### To Fix This:

1. Restart your system and enter your BIOS settings.
   You can enter your BIOS key by repeatedly entering it during bootup. Try pressing the **F2, F5, F8, or Del** keys repeatedly. If those methods don’t work, do a quick Google search on entering your BIOS settings based on your motherboard manufacturer.
2. Once you get to the BIOS menu, look for the secondary menu under **Video Settings, Graphics Settings, or VGA Memory Size.** You should find it under the Advanced menu.
3. From there, you can adjust the **DVMT pre-allocated VRAM** to the size
   that suits your need.
4. Save the configuration and restart your computer. You should see
   your new VRAM count at your next start-up.

Hope That Helped, This Problem Is Mostly Related to BIOS you can search online there are a lot of guides on this topic