Detect the origin for my computer's problems, probably hardware-related
In the past couple of weeks my computer shows more and more problems. I think it might be a hardware problem, since most of my setup is 13 years old and it worked before with the same OS. However, I don't know where to start to find out which component causes the problem.
SETUP
OS:
ElementaryOS 7.1 Horus (based on Ubuntu LTS 22.04.3)
Hardware:
Intel CPU i5-2400 (no additional graphics card), 8GB DDR3 RAM, 2 HDDs + 1 SSD, mainboard
(in dmesg it says this "Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P8H67-M PRO, BIOS 1003 05/10/2011")
The hardware I described above are my suspects. However, the SSD is new and I recently installed the OS freshly onto it (before that I only had the HDDs). The system is now faster, but the problems are the same. So I think it's not a problem related to the drives.
PROBLEMS
Most frequent problem is browser (or browser tab) crashes (both Firefox and Epiphany). Most frequent == multiple times a day. I re-installed Firefox and also tried with Troubleshooting Mode and new profile. Result is the same. I had the impression that it happens more on rich websites (like Youtube) and less when I only read a blog - but sometimes it immediately crashes on startup as well.
Other problem is that sometimes the system completely freezes. Happens from time to time.
Also, I have a problem that my WLAN connection keeps disconnecting and forgetting the password (but I am not sure if that is related).
LOGS
I looked into dmesg and opened firefox via terminal to see error logs.
dmesg:
[ 2868.450095] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:00000000bb41f266 type:MM_FILEPAGES val:-1
[ 2868.450107] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:00000000bb41f266 type:MM_ANONPAGES val:1
[ 2883.823534] rtw_8822bu 1-1.6:1.0: firmware failed to leave lps state

firefox terminal:
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 8759
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...

After this the CrashReporter crashed (???).
Please guide me towards how to find out which hardware component (or what else?) might be causing these issues.
UPDATE 30th June
I tested two things:

Ubuntu Live System (24.4. from stick): booting worked, but Ubuntu notified me with a pop up about "System program error" (or something like that) multiple times. Also, Firefox (was preinstalled and I imported no settings/profile) tabs crashed in something like 5 minutes of surfing the net.

I installed memtest86+ and ran it (old BIOS installation, so I added it to and ran it from grub). It did two passes with a lot of tests each and no error showed.


=> probably neither the RAM nor the disks nor the OS
Ideas for my next steps?
UPDATE 6th July
I opened the computer case and looked at cables etc. Nothing looked strange or bad to me - there was even less dust inside than I expected. Everything was firmly in place.
How can I check for changed BIOS settings?
Is there any way to check CPU, mainboard, power supply for failures?
UPDATE 10th July
My BIOS offers different performance settings. Because of the system's slowness, I had switched to the highest performance setting. Now I switched back to "energy saving" and since then I had no browser crashes anymore. Yay :) Slow but steady again.
Into which direction would that point? Power supply too weak? CPU not up to full speed anymore?

To eliminate any OS/software issue, create a boot USB, perhaps Ubuntu 22.04 (or 20.04 LTS)  itself, rather than elementary OS derivative, and run from it for a while. If there are no issues, all hardware, except possibly SSD, is OK. Then you might install that OS on  a separate partition of the SSD, to see if the SSD is involved.

@DrMoishePippik I followed your advice and updated my question with the results

The crashes from USB boot lead me to believe a hardware or firmware issue. First, check all cables and device sockets: wiggle gently to remove oxides or other junk (fungus hyphae have been known to infiltrate a connector), reseat firmly. Look for any broken solder connections, particularly around network card. Check if any BIOS settings changed. [Beware of updating BIOS, since utility is Windows-based: https://superuser.com/questions/29221/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-computer-from-a-failed-bios-update ]

@DrMoishePippik I checked the hardware and updated my question. Hope you have some more ideas.
